# sencha touch pass variables from component to component

Tags: sencha-touch

I understood that by calling MyDetailView.Update(record.data) I send record.data to MyDetailView and can access them in the xtemplate:

```
tpl:'<h1>{title}></h1>'
```

Additionally I want to use record.data in an item of xtype 'map':

```
items: [
  {
    xtype: 'map',
    getLocation: true,
    padding: '20 0 0 0',
    mapOptions: {
      center : new google.maps.LatLng(lng, lat), // <-- here record.data.lat
      zoom : 15,
      mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      navigationControl: true,
      navigationControlOptions: {
        style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
      }
    }
  }
]
```

How can I access the data in MyDetailView?

Thanks

----------------EDIT------------------

I add my complete code. In the list view I call an AppDetailcard.update(record.data).

```
var AppDetailcard = new Ext.Panel ({
    id: 'detailcard',
    styleHtmlContent: false,
    tpl: 'my {lat}', //<-- here it works
    fullscreen: true,
    dockedItems: [AppDetailcardToolbar],
    items     : [
        {
            xtype: 'map',
            getLocation: true,
            mapOptions: {
                center : new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng), //<-- here it does not
                zoom : 15,
                mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                navigationControl: true,
                navigationControlOptions: {
                style: google.maps.NavigationControlStyle.DEFAULT
                            }

            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Looking at that code, I'm guessing it might be this.lng & this.lat ?

Comment: @MozMorris I forget to mention that I did try this without success. While it does not throw any error the GMap is not displaying at all.

Answer (score 0):

You have to also *push* the new record into your items array.

```
this.down('map').setMapCenter({
    latitude: newRecord.data.latitude,
    longitude: newRecord.data.longitude
});
```

I usually push *records*, not data, into the view and then use the updateRecord event to accept that record and push it further down the items array.

Look at the navigationview example on the Sencha site, in the Show.js view file, where they do exactly that.